# Chrome Extension: popup.js and content.js won't talk

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying for hours to get popup.js to talk with the rest of my chrome extension using chrome api's `sendMessage` and `onMessage`. For testing purposes, all I want right now is to log something onto my currently active tab when a button is pressed on popup.js. This seems like it should be simple, but I just can't  figure out what the problem is. Would really appreciate any help and explanation!

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<p>testing</p>
<input type="submit" id="clickme" value="button">
</body>
```

popup.js

```
 function popup(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
     var activeTab = tabs[0];
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
 }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click",popup)
});
```

content.js (I expect this to log 'started' onto console of my active tab)

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
    console.log('started')

    }
  }
);
```

Just in case it applies, this is the manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name": "extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js":["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","content.js"]
        }],
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a  `<script src="popup.js"></script>` to your *popup.html*. Right now your *popup.js* is not ever being run.

Comment: It's strange that it only logs to the browser's console when a new tab is created, not on the active tab